# Assigning individual keys of object stored in jQuery.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I have custom data stored on elements using [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
<div id="mydiv" data-test='{"1":"apple", "2":"banana"}'>Custom data</div>
```

I know I can access individual keys of the object stored in `data-test` using

```
$('#mydiv').data('test')["1"]
```

But **is it ok** to **re-assign** **individual keys** like this? It works, but it isn't documented. Secondly, on inspecting the element using browser's developer tools, I still see the old value i.e. "apple" in this case. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tTJ9U/)

```
$('#mydiv').data('test')["1"] = "pear"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.data()` to set a value, won't change the values in the element while you inspect it, it would store that data internally. If you want to reflect those changes to the DOM element, then you should use `.attr()` like this,

```
  $('#mydiv').data('test')["1"] = "pear"
  $('#mydiv').attr('data-test', JSON.stringify($('#mydiv').data('test')));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tTJ9U/1/)

Inspect that particular element to verify the changes.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was just reading a similar discussion in comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17762906/781695). However, I find updating `.attr()` a tedious step. Is there any downside if I don't update it and simply keep using `.data()['key'] = val` method?

Comment: @buffer There's no down side in it, you are doing the things in a right way. I just tried to explain you how to reflect the changes in the DOM elements and it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Specifically, jQuery loads the data keys at page load into an internal data array, which is what is used when calls to `.data()` are made. Provided you continue accessing the `data()` method, and not the attributes directly, you wont encounter issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#mydiv').data('test')["1"] = "pear";
$('#mydiv').attr('data-test',function(_,attr){
   return JSON.stringify(attr);
});
```