# How to modify data in DOM too with jQuery.data

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i edit a DOM element with `jQuery.data` function, DOM code is not really updated:

Ex, for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo" data-price="100">Foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And:

```
console.log($('#foo').data('price'));
$('#foo').data('price', 90);
console.log($('#foo').data('price'));
console.log('[data-price=90]: ' + $('[data-price=90]').length);
console.log('[data-price=100]: ' + $('[data-price=100]').length);
```

Output is:

```
100
90
"[data-price=90]: 0"
"[data-price=100]: 1"
```

(This exemple is available [here](https://jsbin.com/veluvuxexe/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

So, after `jQuery.data` usage, `div#foo` still have 90 as price. How to really modify it with jQuery method ?

Comment: Please use `$(element).data({key:value}); //to set data` and `$(element).data(key); // to get data` I understand what you are trying to seek but the dom might not be updated and data tag generally works behind the scenes

Comment: I'm not sure if .data( ) method allows for changing the property value inside *.html. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762906/cant-update-data-attribute-value-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bux is on point because, as you can see from [here](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/):

> Note that `.removeData()` will only remove data from jQuery's internal
>   `.data()` cache, and any corresponding `data-` attributes on the element
>   will not be removed. A later call to data() will therefore re-retrieve
>   the value from the `data-` attribute. To prevent this, use `.removeAttr()`
>   alongside `.removeData()` to remove the data- attribute as well. Prior
>   to jQuery 1.4.3, as `data()` did not use `data-` attributes, this was not
>   an issue.

Thus, there's the cached data, which can be manipulated by using `.data()` and there's the corresponding `data-` attribute.

When you change the cached data via `.data('price', 90)`, the attribute `data-price="100"` is still intact and does not get changed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to modify attribute to:

```
console.log($('#foo').data('price'));
$('#foo').attr('data-price', 90);
$('#foo').data('price', 90);
console.log($('#foo').data('price'));
console.log('[data-price=90]: ' + $('[data-price=90]').length);
console.log('[data-price=100]: ' + $('[data-price=100]').length);
```

Will output:

```
100
90
"[data-price=90]: 1"
"[data-price=100]: 0"
```