# How to add jquery variable into span class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Barfiller (https://github.com/9bitStudios/barfiller).
Everything works, but I want to set the data-percentage value in the span class (now set as "50") to be dynamically filled via a JQuery variable.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bar1" class="barfiller">
    <span class="tip"></span>
    <span class="fill" data-percentage="50"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var projectstatus = data.d.projectstatus;
    $('#data-percentage').text(projectstatus);
}
```

Regards,
Chris

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update data-attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762906/cant-update-data-attribute-value) ... (there is no element with a data-percentage id, but that's what you try to get with your jQuery selector)

Comment: In your case, you need to use this for change `data-percentage` : `$("spam.fill").data("percentage", projectstatus);`

Answer (score 1):

I have added a timeout of **2 seconds** before executing `onQuerySucceeded()` function as I thought it might be handy for you in case, you are loading the new percentage after making an api (service) call. Hope it helps you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('data percentage: ' + $(".fill").attr('data-percentage'));
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // after 2 seconds
    var responseJson = {};
    responseJson.d = { projectstatus: 15 };
    onQuerySucceeded(responseJson);
  }, 2000);
});

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
  $('.fill').attr("data-percentage", data.d.projectstatus);
  console.log('data percentage: ' + $(".fill").attr('data-percentage'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar1" class="barfiller">
    <span class="tip"></span>
    <span class="fill" data-percentage="50"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bar1 .fill").attr("data-percentage", projectstatus);
```

Comment: Generally better to use `.data` for `data-` attributes.

Comment: In fact, in this case, you probably *have* to use `.data` as it's likely the "barfiller" will be using `.data` to read the value and that will use jquery's internal value before it uses the attribute - so changing the attribute will have *no effect* on the desired plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to make it work.

You have to use `$(...).data( key, value)` to set a new value to a `data-...` field in **JQuery**.

In **JS** you woulr use `.setAttribute("data-percentage", "50");` for example.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  console.log($(".fill").data('percentage'));
  onQuerySucceeded(40);
  console.log($(".fill").data('percentage'));
});

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var projectstatus = data;
    $('#bar1 [data-percentage]').data('percentage', projectstatus);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar1" class="barfiller">
    <span class="tip"></span>
    <span class="fill" data-percentage="50"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of adding an ID to the HTML you could also only change the selector to `$('[data-percentage]')` or maybe even better `$('#bar1 [data-percentage]')`

Comment: You are right it always depends. If the code is generated you have to check the possibilities. I changed my solution to your second suggestion.