# With jQuery, update the value of a data element attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I update the value of a data element attribute ?

This is my HTML:

```
<a href="" data-action="add-to-cart">Add</a>
```

This is my JS:

```
$('a[data-action="add-to-cart"], a[data-action="remove-from-cart"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).data('action') == 'add-to-cart') {
        $(this).data('action', 'remove-from-cart');
    }

    else {
        $(this).data('action', 'add-to-cart');
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your issue here? Errors, what happens when you click the button, etc. Basically, what is wrong with what you've done

Comment: What you have [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bdru85aq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

So I read on SO, and I found a solution that works for my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585821/9603642

```
$('a[data-action="add-to-cart"], a[data-action="remove-from-cart"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).data('action') == 'add-to-cart') {
        $(this).attr('data-action', 'remove-from-cart');
        $(this).data('action', 'remove-from-cart');
    }

    else {
        $(this).attr('data-action', 'add-to-cart');
        $(this).data('action', 'add-to-cart');
    }
});
```

I add to use `attr` and `data`.

Answer (score -6):

How to set any attribute in jquery:

```
$(this).attr('data-action', 'add-to-cart');
```